# How does this code enable the redirection flow?

Tags: express, nginx, proxy, passport.js

I have a frontend `www.myfrontend.tech` and a backend `www.mybackend.io`. My previous developer managed to realize third-party authentications (like Microsoft) with PassportJS. But when looking at his code, I could not understand the flow and how the code enables this. Here is the code:

In the `.conf` of nginx of `www.myfrontend.tech`:

```
upstream mybackend {
   server www.mybackend.io:443;
}

server {
    location ~ /socialLoginSuccess {                                                                                            
        rewrite ^ '/#/socialLoginSuccess' redirect;
    }

    location ~ /auth/(.*) {                                                                                            
        proxy_pass  https://mybackend/front/auth/$1?$query_string;
        proxy_set_header Host www.myfrontend.tech;
    }
    ... ...
}
```

In `frontend/src/router.tsx` of `www.myfrontend.tech` in ReactJS:

```
function RouterConfig({ history }: any) {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/socialLoginSuccess">
            <SocialLoginSuccess />
          </Route>
          ... ...
```

In `app.js` of `www.mybackend.io` in NodeJS+ExpressJS+PassportJS:

```
var _front = require('./routes/front');
app.use('/front', _front);
```

In `routes/front.js` of `www.mybackend.io`:

```
router.get('/auth/microsoft', passport.authenticate('microsoft', { scope: ['User.Read'] }));
router.get('/auth/microsoft/callback', passport.authenticate('microsoft', {
  successRedirect: '/auth/signinSuccess',
  failureRedirect: '/auth/signinFailure',
  failureFlash: true
}))

router.get('/auth/signinSuccess', function (req, res, next) {
  res.redirect("/socialLoginSuccess");
})
```

In `passport.module.js`:

```
var Microsoft = (function() {
  function Microsoft() {}
  Microsoft.prototype.enable = function() {
    var MicrosoftStrategy = require("passport-microsoft").Strategy;
    passport.use(
      "microsoft",
      new MicrosoftStrategy(
        {
          clientID: keys.MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID,
          clientSecret: keys.MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET,
          callbackURL: `/auth/microsoft/callback`
        },
        this.loginSuccessfully
      )
    );
  };
  return Microsoft;
})();
```

During tests of this authentication, I can see in the address bar `www.myfrontend.tech/auth/google` and `www.myfrontend.tech/#/socialLoginSuccess` after signing in.

My question is, for example, where `successRedirect: '/auth/signinSuccess'` goes (backend or frontend)? and where does `res.redirect("/socialLoginSuccess")` go? How was it enabled by the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow:

1. User go to `www.myfrontend.tech/auth/microsoft` (forwarded to `https://mybackend.io/front/auth/microsoft` on the backend, since it matches `location ~ /auth/(.*)` on your nginx configuration)
2. It will redirect to Microsoft auth page
3. After user clicked authorize, it will redirected to the callback URL on your Microsoft Oauth App, which in your case is `www.frontend.tech/auth/microsoft/callback` (forwarded to `https://mybackend.io/front/auth/microsoft/callback` on the backend, since it matches `location ~ /auth/(.*)` on your nginx configuration)
4. On that callback, passport middleware checks if the authorization succeed or not, if it is, it will redirect to `successRedirect` URI, which is `www.frontend.tech/auth/signinSuccess` (forwarded to `https://mybackend.io/front/auth/signinSuccess` on the backend, since it matches `location ~ /auth/(.*)` on your nginx configuration)
5. Express app handle `auth/signinSuccess` success call, and redirects to `/socialLoginSuccess`, since `/socialLoginSuccess` location matches `location ~ /socialLoginSuccess` on your Nginx configuration (not `location ~ /auth/(.*)` therefor there's no proxy pass), it will be redirected to `www.frontend.tech/#/socialLoginSuccess` (by the `rewrite ^ '/#/socialLoginSuccess' redirect;`)
6. Since it's redirected to `www.frontend.tech/#/socialLoginSuccess`, it's now being handled by React router

And to answer your questions:

1. `successRedirect` will go to your front end, so it will be `www.myfrontend.tech/auth/signinSuccess`, but since you have proxy configuration on Nginx, and it matches `location ~ /auth/(.*)`, it's being forwarded to `www.mybackend.io/front/auth/signinSuccess` (read more about [reverse proxy](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/))
2. `res.redirect("/socialLoginSuccess")` will redirect you to `www.frontend.tech/#/socialLoginSuccess`, the reason is mentioned on the 5th flow above